# Chrome 1px background random bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, background

I have a problem with the backgrounds of the divs in chrome, depending of the size of the window (something totally random) the backgrounds of my divs are displayed 1px displaced downwards.

You know any trick to avoid this Chrome bug? With background-attachment: fixed this bug dissapears, but with floating divs the backgrounds turn crazy, then, I can't use this trick.

Comment: Please show which background styles you have used

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried background-size:contain ?

Comment: I can't use that because I use one image with many backgrounds (specially useful with hover and active).

Comment: I use background-position for select the part of the background image. And change that is not an option, because this bug is randomly...